# How to hide H1 title automatically when featured image is used (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a way/code to automatically hide an h1 title whenever a featured image is set? I like my featured image to function as a title, and it seems redundant to have them both. I'm not very experienced with code :(

Comment: Although you aren't experienced with code – is there anything you tried so far?

Comment: .singular-page .entry-header {
  display: none !important;
}

Comment: Ok so I tried that, and replaced the title with the title of my page. Nothing happened. I am so bad at this haha.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a function called [has_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/). You can utilize this function to display an H1 if a featured image is not present:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    the_title();
}
?>
```

That said, using an image in place of an `H1` will probably not be good for your SEO.

Based on @NathanielFlick's suggestion below, you could also use this function to hide the `H1` off the side of the page via CSS if a featured image exists, this way search engines will still pick up the `H1` tag. If you wanted to go that route, your loop would look something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo '<style type="text/css">h1{position:absolute;left:-100%;}</style>';
        }
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This would work in your `single.php` template, but you would have to tie in the post ID for your index page to target only the `H1` for that specific post, otherwise if one post on the page doesn't have a featured image, all `H1s` will be hidden off screen whether the post has a featured image or not.

Alright, for your specific theme, it looks like the post ID is being added in as an ID and a class, so you could set it up like this:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<style type="text/css">#post-' . $post->ID . ' h1{position:absolute;left:-100%;}</style>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a good solution as long as the h1 is always present. I'd say when image is present the H1 is positioned off the screen but still in the document so it's SEO-friendly.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I would agree, but I'm pretty sure Google [penalizes sites for doing that](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en).

Comment: No it doesn't. It's much better, also, than having no H1 at all.

Comment: Updated answer based on suggestion from @NathanielFlick

Comment: Ok this looks like what I'd like to do. I know I need a title but visually it looks horrible :( Any other suggestions? 

here's an example: http://thetraditionalmillennial.com/cloth-diaper-budget/

Featured image is great for pinterest, and twitter, but I don't need the title since it's in the image. It's pretty redundant. What would an effective solution for this be?

Comment: then h1 {position: absolute: top: 0; left: -9999px; width: 200px;} to put the title off the page, but still in the source.

Comment: Hmm, well I certainly don't want it doing that for every post, but I also don't want to be messing with code every time I have an article that uses a featured image and doesn't need to show the title. I wish there was an easy way about this :(

Comment: You wouldn't have to mess with anything, once you have the function set up, everything happens automatically. You would just need to be sure that the post ID is in the class of the post object, then you could target only the H1 within that post.

Comment: Added some code at the very bottom that pertains specifically to the theme you are using. You would want to set this up in both the `index` template as well as the `single` template.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm gonna attempt this right now. Wish me luck :$

Comment: Good luck! As long as you're vaguely familiar  working with PHP it should be pretty easy. Also, I would suggest setting up a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and making these changes there, that way if your theme ever gets updated your changes won't be overwritten.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, however developers have different ways of setting up their themes, the files could have different filenames and/or the loop that displays the list of posts on your homepage could be in a file other than index.php.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I'll have to figure out the child-theme stuff next.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out! Feel free to post a new question if you run into any issues setting up a child theme, it's pretty straight-forward though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [has_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) function to check if a featured image is set.

This could be:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail(); // the thumbnail
} else {
    the_title(); // the title
}
```

Comment: can I make it check if the featured image is set, then hide the title?

Comment: This is what i've posted. If the post has a thumbnail, show this thumbnail. Else, display the title.

Answer (score -2):

It just so happens that I've found the solution. Get a Custom CSS plugin like Simple Custom CSS and use the following CSS.

One of these lines is unnecessary, but it'll definitely work :)

```
.entry-header { display: none;}

.content-section { padding: 0px; }

.page-title-wrap { display: none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 846px) {
    .content-area, .content-sidebar {
        padding-top: 0px;
     }
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, the h1 is only hidden visually but still in the document which is a really bad practice.

Comment: Technically, Google scans the html not the css so hiding h1's isn't bad for SEO.

Comment: Really bad practice because of SEO? Here is the page I'd like the title to be hidden - http://thetraditionalmillennial.com/favorite-breastfeeding-products/

As you can see it's really redundant to have the title almost twice. I've read that google won't penalize for this? Really conflicting opinions out there. Visually, it looks terrible either way.

Comment: PS tried that code and it hid the featured image too, which is what I want to stay.

Comment: Actually I am more concerned about accessibility. Using `display: none` on the `h1` also hides the headline from screen readers. Since the `h1` is the most important headline on a page, you will have a hard time figuring out what the page is about.

Comment: Starting to think I should not be using the featured image thing and just placing the image within the text. :-\